# What's wrong with my Kendo UI ClientTemplate code?

Tags: kendo-ui, client-templates, kendo-template

```
columns.Bound(e => e.CreateDate).ClientTemplate("# if (CreateDate != null){#"
                                                          + @Html.Action("ChangeDate", "Home", new {date = "#= CreateDate #"}) +
                                                          "#}  else if ((CreateDate) == null)" +
                                                          "{#-#}#");
```

The ChangeDate action add year to date, but I got the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'date' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.String ChangeDate(System.DateTime)'

as error says the date value is null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CreateDate` can be `null`, you need to check for `data.CreateDate` instead.

```
columns.Bound(e => e.CreateDate).ClientTemplate("# if (data.CreateDate != null){#"
                                                      + @Html.Action("ChangeDate", "Home", new {date = "#= CreateDate #"}) +
                                                      "#}  else if ((data.CreateDate) == null)" +
                                                      "{#-#}#");
```